# VncServer can't restart because of Xvnc

Tags: linux, vnc

I'm working on a Red Hat Linux server. VNC server started to act weird (i.e. the sessions became Spartan). So I decided to reboot VNC server.

I keep getting the following error message: "unable to start Xvnc, exiting"

Does anyone know what this means? The best thing I could come up via Google was that some packages needed to be updated, but everything was already up to date.

Answer (score 2):

Where is your Xvnc path? As our last case, it is /usr/local/bin/Xvnc instead of the correct one /usr/bin/Xvnc.